# Change event not working on Bootstrap 4 calender

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, calendar

I am using this [dateTimePicker](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Events/#changedatetimepicker)

Here is my html:-

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sdating_1"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Day</label>
        <div class="input-group date" id="sDatePicker_1" data-target-input="nearest"  data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#sDatePicker_1" data-toggle="datetimepicker" id="sdating_1" name="sdate[]" placeholder="Select Day"/>
            <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#sDatePicker_1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have added the library like this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('front_assets/assets/plugins/bootstrap-4-calender/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Here is my code:-

```
$('body').on('focus',"div[id*='DatePicker']", function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker({
        format: 'L',
    }).on('change.datetimepicker', function(e) { alert('hello')});
});
```

However, I am not getting any alert. I am getting an error

```
TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker(...) is undefined
```

But when I am removing the on change event like this:-

```
$('body').on('focus',"div[id*='DatePicker']", function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker({
        format: 'L',
     });
});
```

I am not getting any error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the plugin isn't chainable

Try adding `on()` directly to the element object instead

```
$('body').on('focus',"div[id*='DatePicker']", function(){
    var $dp = $(this);
    $dp.datetimepicker({
        format: 'L',
    });

    $dp.on('change.datetimepicker', function(e) { alert('hello')});
});
```

Comment: Note will add multiple listeners when focused multiple times. not sure why you would use focus to initialize the plugin to be honest

Answer (score -1):

```
$(this).datetimepicker({
    format: 'L',
})
```

Returns undefined, so you cannot stack the on handler.
I would suggest changing your code to this:

```
$('#DatePicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'L'
})

$('#DatePicker').datetimepicker().on('dp.change',function(e){
    console.log(e)
    alert('hello')
})
```

Comment: That's from Laravel. In Laravel, you load file like this.

Comment: Why would it work in one case if this was the problem?

Comment: I see, I have changed my anwser